# Python - Access hierarchical dict element from list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

Let's say I have a regular "dict-of-dicts" as follows:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = {}
d['a']['b'] = 3
```

I can of course access the element using `d['a']['b']`.

In my case, I have a recursive application, in which I keep the current state as a list of keys. So I would have

```
my_key = ['a', 'b']
```

How do I access the value 3, using `my_key`? The issue, of course, is that `my_key` can be arbitrarily long (deep).

I realize I can write another traversal function or so, but it seems like there should be a straightforward way of doing so. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is a common enough (or sensible enough) case to warrant a function. Just write your own - it's like 4 lines.

Comment: Can you fix your example as it makes no sense, also how deeply can the keys be nested?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry, fixed it now..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to iteratively index each layer of dict with a different key:

```
>>> from functools import reduce #only necessary in 3.X
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = {} #I'm assuming this is what you meant to type
>>> d['a']['b'] = 3
>>> keys = ("a", "b")
>>> reduce(dict.get, keys, d)
3
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently dictionary keys can only be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) types, `list` (`ListType`) is not one of them, so if you try to specify a list as a dictionary key:

```
{}[[]]
```

you'll get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.
```

You could enhance the current dictionary, allowing to specify a list as a key, and iterate over the list on inner objects. Here's the code (note that it only takes care of the *get*/*read* part):

```
from types import DictType, ListType

class EnhancedDictType(DictType):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key and isinstance(key, ListType):
            new_obj = self
            for item in key:
                new_obj = new_obj[item]
            return new_obj
        else:
            return super(EnhancedDictType, self).__getitem__(key)

dict = EnhancedDictType
```

Here's also some test code:

```
d = dict()
d[1] = dict()
d[1][2] = dict({3: 4})
d[(1, 2, 3)] = 5
print d
print d[1]
print d[1][2]
print d[[1, 2]]
print d[[1 ,2, 3]]
print d[(1, 2, 3)]
```